# div рядом с div

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть 2 дива и их нужно расположить рядом.
Сейчас блоки отображаются друг под другом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже перепробовал и `float:left;` и `white-space: nowrap;`

```html
<div  style="background-color: white;padding-left: 20px;padding-top: 10px;border-radius: 10px;margin-right:20px;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;">БЛОК1
 </div>
  <div style="margin-left: 73%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #777777;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;border:1px solid #000;">БЛОК2
     </div>
```

Comment: покажите Ваш код, в котором будет html и css (как Вы сами пробовали сделать)

Comment: @Alex предоставил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нет `inline-block` для первого блока. По умолчанию у блока происходит перенос строк в начале и в конце содержимого, поэтому свойство `inline-block` нужно указывать и для первого блока тоже.

```html
<div style="display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;">БЛОК1
</div>
<div style="/*margin-left: 73%; закомментировано для наглядности*/
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #777777;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;border:1px solid #000;">БЛОК2
</div>
```

[Тест](http://jsfiddle.net/n245ov9x/)

[Документация](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display)

Помимо `inline-block`, одним из способов выравнивать блоки является [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: А ещё можно использовать grid и table (не тег)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы внимательно изучали `CSS` то там есть такая гибкая вещь как flex

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```css
.blocks-wrapper 
{
display:flex;
}

.block
{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks-wrapper">
  <div class = "block">
    Блок 1
  </div>
  <div class = "block">
  Блок 2
  </div>
</div>
```